# workflow for npm forking and editing

Tags: reactjs, github, npm

I'd like to use https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar.
But it doesn't say how I should include the component in my existing project.

For python library, I would clone it and `pip install -e github-address` and modify the code.
I can commit the change to my fork repo.
(So that I can fetch upstream update later on)

with npm,

- I make fork.
- npm install the fork.
- modify the code.
- but how do I commit the change to my fork?

Answer (score 1):

You commit the change to your fork using git and push it up to github. Once your fork on github has your code changes, you either need to (1) try to get your changes into the original fork by submitting a pull request and, once merged, have the owner of react-big-calendar publish a new version to npm, (2) reference your fork from your package.json [using a github URL](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), or (3) publish your modified version of the project as a *new* package to npm (it would be called something other than react-big-calendar).

I wouldn't try #1 unless your changes are applicable to a wider audience. I wouldn't try #3 unless your changes are applicable to a wider audience and the author of react-big-calendar chooses to reject your changes. If your changes are not applicable to a wider audience but you'd really like to use npm to host your packages, you can sign up for [npm's private modules feature](https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules).

Comment: Another use case for (3) might be if the repo you forked does not have its package.json in the root. See [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974); npm has opted not to support github url installation in such cases, so (2) is simply not feasible.